# Random numbers with Math.random() in Java

Tags: java, random

For generating random numbers, I've used the formula:

`(int)(Math.random() * max) + min`

The formula I find on Google always seem to be:

`(int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)`

Which one's right? As far as I know, I've never gotten a number that was out of my range with my formula

Comment: As I'm sure a half-dozen answers seeking easy points will say by the time I refresh the page:  yours is incorrect.  Your `max` should really be named `range` or `width`.

Comment: you seem to be a lucky guy.

Answer (score 17):

Your formula generates numbers between min and min + max.

The one Google found generates numbers between min and max.

Google wins!

Comment: For the sake of completeness, when you say 'complete', do you mean including `min` and excluding `max`?

Answer (score 11):

A better approach is:

```
int x = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Your formula generates numbers between `min` and `min + max`.

```
Random random = new Random(1234567);
int min = 5;
int max = 20;
while (true) {
    int x = (int)(Math.random() * max) + min;
    System.out.println(x);
    if (x < min || x >= max) { break; }
}
```

Result:

```
10
16
13
21 // Oops!!
```

See it online here: [ideone](http://ideone.com/y8rYZ)

Answer (score 6):

Yours: Lowest possible is min, highest possible is max+min-1

Google: Lowest possible is min, highest possible is max-1

Comment: Math.random() doesn't return 1

Answer (score 4):

if `min=10` and `max=100`:

```
(int)(Math.random() * max) + min
```

gives a result between 10 and 110, while

```
(int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
```

gives a result between 10 and 100, so **they are very different formulas**. What's important here is clarity, so whatever you do, make sure the code makes it clear what is being generated.

(PS. the first makes more sense if you change the variable 'max' to be called 'range')

Answer (score 3):

The first one generates numbers in the wrong range, while the second one is correct.

To show that the first one is incorrect, let's say `min` is 10 and `max` is 20. In other words, the result is expected to be greater than or equal to ten, and strictly less than twenty. If `Math.random()` returns `0.75`, the result of the first formula is `25`, which is outside the range.

Answer (score 3):

Google is right :-)

Google's formula creates numbers between: **min and max**
Your formula creates numbers between: **min and (min+max)**

Answer (score 2):

If `min = 5`, and `max = 10`, and `Math.random()` returns (almost) 1.0, the generated number will be (almost) 15, which is clearly more than the chosen `max`.

Relatedly, this is why every random number API should let you specify min and max explicitly. You shouldn't have to write error-prone maths that are tangential to your problem domain.

Comment: Math.random() is always lower than 1.0.

Comment: @F.J I've added an "almost" for the sake of correctness; I chose 1.0 because it's easier to understand an example with integers.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = (int) (10 +Math.random()*11);
```

this will give you random number between 10 to 20.

the key here is:

```
a + Math.random()*b
```

a starting num (10) and ending num is max number (20) - a (10)  + 1 (11)

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Jason, looking at the Javadoc for Math.random, it returns a double >= 0.0 but < 1.0. Assuming the decimal precision is as shown (tenths), (10+Math.random()*11 would return values in range 10..19, not 20. [Math.random()'s max val is 0.9. 0.9 * 11 = 9.9. 10 + 9.9 = 19.9. Casting int reduces it to 19 since that truncates the 19.9 value, not rounding it (Math.round(double_val) would return a long value of 20 in this case). So I think to get a range of 10..20, you'd need this instead: int i = (int) (10 + Math.random()*12); if you or anyone else thinks this is incorrect, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

> Math.random()
>
> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to
>   0.0 and less than 1.0.

Now it depends on what you want to accomplish. When you want to have Numbers from 1 to 100 for example you just have to add

```
(int)(Math.random()*100)
```

So 100 is the range of values. When you want to change the start of the range to 20 to 120 you have to add +20 at the end.

So the formula is:

```
(int)(Math.random()*range) + min
```

And you can always calculate the range with max-min, thats why Google gives you that formula.

Answer (score 1):

There's a small problem with the formula that you found on Google.
It should be:
`(int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)`
not
`(int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)` .

`max - min + 1` is the range in which random numbers can be generated

Comment: Depends if you want your random number to have an inclusive upper range, which oftentimes is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` generates a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

So `(int)(Math.random() * max)` ranges from `0` to `max-1` inclusive.

Then `(int)(Math.random() * max) + min` ranges from `min` to `max + min - 1`, which is not what you want.

Google's formula is correct.