# When I run the code the output is not the same as I expected

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

This is the main class

```
package project_datastructure;
    
public class Project_DataStructure {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    sys system = new sys(10, 6); 
     system.initializeStudents();
     system.initializeCourses(); 
    system.assignCoursesToStudents();
        system.listCoursesTakenByStudent(1);
        System.out.println();
        system.listStudentsEnrolledInCourse("Mathematics");
    }

}
```

The system class

```
package project_datastructure;
public class sys { 
    Node[] students;
     Node[] courses;
    public sys(int numStudents, int numCourses) {
        students = new Node[numStudents];
        courses = new Node[numCourses];
    }
    
    public void listCoursesTakenByStudent(int studentId) {
        System.out.println("Courses taken by student with ID " + studentId + ":");
        for (Node student : students) {
            if (student.id == studentId) {
                Node current = student.down;
                while (current != null) {
                    System.out.println(current.name);
                    current = current.next;
                }
                return; // No need to continue looping once we find the student
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Student with ID " + studentId + " not found.");
    }
    
    public void listStudentsEnrolledInCourse(String courseName) {
        boolean courseFound = false;
        for (Node course : courses) {
            if (course != null && course.name.equals(courseName)) {
                courseFound = true;
                Node current = course.down; // Assuming 'down' points to the list of enrolled students
                if (current == null) {
                    System.out.println("No students are enrolled in " + courseName + ".");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("Students enrolled in course " + courseName + ":");
                while (current != null) {
                    System.out.println(current.id); // Print the ID of the student
                    current = current.next; // Assuming 'next' points to the next student in the list
                }
                break; // No need to continue looping once we find the course
            }
        }
        if (!courseFound) {
            System.out.println("Course " + courseName + " not found.");
        }
    }
    
    public void initializeStudents() {
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            students[i] = new Node(i + 1); 
        }
    }
    
    // Method to initialize courses
    public void initializeCourses() {
        String[] names = {"Mathematics", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology", "History", "Computer Science"};
        for (int i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
            courses[i] = new Node(names[i]); // IDs start from 1
        }
    }
    
    public void assignCoursesToStudents() {
        for (Node student : students) {
            // Assigning 3 courses to each student
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                int courseId = (int) (Math.random() * courses.length); // Randomly select a course
                Node courseNode = new Node(courses[courseId].name); // Create a node for the course
                if (student.down == null) {
                    student.down = courseNode;
                } else {
                    Node currentCourse = student.down;
                    while (currentCourse.next != null) {
                        currentCourse = currentCourse.next;
                    }
                    currentCourse.next = courseNode;
                }
    
                // Link the student to the course
                Node currentCourse = courses[courseId];
                if (currentCourse.down == null) {
                    currentCourse.down = new Node(student.id); // Linking student ID to the course
                } else {
                    Node temp = currentCourse.down;
                    while (temp.next != null) {
                        temp = temp.next;
                    }
                    temp.next = new Node(student.id); // Linking student ID to the course
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Node class

```
package project_datastructure;
    
class Node {
     int id;
     String name;
     Node next;
     Node down;
    public Node(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.next = null;
        this.down = null;
    }
    
    // Constructor for course nodes
    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.next = null;
        this.down = null;
    }

}
```

This is the output:

```
Courses taken by student with ID 1:
Chemistry
Mathematics
Mathematics

Students enrolled in course Mathematics:
1
1
3
7
7
8
8
9
```

I expected to print it right like, for example, this is the output:

```
Courses taken by student with ID 1:
Chemistry
Mathematics
physics

Students enrolled in course Mathematics:
1
3
7
8
8
9
```

Comment: Start by fixing your indenting, to make code easier to read. Your IDE will do that for you. And follow Java naming conventions: Class name starts with uppercase letter, method names start with lowercase letter.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: First issue - [Math.random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) generates a double between 0.0 and 1.0, so it's never going to pick that third course without [a proper implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923004/7665043) that produces a number between min and max.

Comment: Brother, the best advice I could give you would be to use your debugger to step through your code.  You can check all your variables at each point, and see exactly where they're changing in a way that differs from what you expect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is two lines with (student ID?) 8 expected?! Um - try to draw the data structure with one student in mode than one course: what are `next` & `down` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the random-operation may result in multiple assignments of the same course to the same student - hence the duplicate listing of Mathematics for student 1 and the duplicate student-ids (1, 7 and 8) for Mathematics in your result.

The random operation does not exclude previous results from further calls. In order to get a course at one times at the most you should use an intermediate Set and assign the courses to the students when the size of the set reaches 3. That'll eliminate duplicates.